# Extend Umbraco 7.1.1 Multi Tree Node Picker

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-ucommerce

I am trying to extend the Multi Node Tree Picker (MNTP) in Umbraco but am running into some trouble. I am used to writing property editors in the new umbraco 7 angular style, so the MNTP is a bit foreign to me. I want to be able to connect my uCommerce Catalog Tree to the MNTP. I feel like this should be fairly simple as all that I should need to do is hook up the uCommerce tree to the MNTP. I am in the Umbraco.Web.PropertyEditors dll, but it isn't really helping me too much. Any pointers to get me started in the right direction would be much appreciated. I could then share this as a new package if I can get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating your own property editor that simply uses the Umbraco dialogService to pick the uCommerce product.

You can use the Yo Umbraco template generator to build a scaffolded package:

https://github.com/warrenbuckley/generator-umbraco